# How can a TCP server application handle reconnects in response to stale connections?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The main loop of basic server looks like this currently:

```
            ConcurrentDictionary<EndPoint,Connection> connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<EndPoint, Monitor>();

            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, config.Port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                HandleNewConnection(client);
            }

    private void HandleNewConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        var key = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        var connection = new Connection(client);
        connections[key] = connection;
        //run the connection client/server stuff, basically just Reads in a loop
        _ = connection.MonitorAsync();
    }
```

There are two specific cases I want to handle:

1. The connection is lost. This seems fairly easy, doing something like `_ = connection.MonitorAsync().ContinueWith( () => connections.Remove(key)` ?
2. A new connection comes in *from an existing client*. TCP connections are not great at detecting faults unless you write to them, so it's quite plausible a client could try to send data, detect a problem, drop the connection, and reconnect - and my server thinks the connection is still valid. The first it knows is a new connection comes in from a client it thinks is already connected.

In 2. it is conceptually quite simple that we look-up the existing connection from the same client endpoint, terminate it and store a `Connection` into `connections`.

*But* now if I'm not careful my continuation from 1. will kick in *after* 2, and remove the *new* element from the dictionary.

There must be a neat pattern but I keep tying myself in knots trying to figure it out. Servers must handle this situation all the time and need to be accurate not to accrue a huge pile of dead connection objects. What would be a normal way to handle this, other than a more stateless approach where `Connections` doesn't exist?

Comment: BTW: I know `EndPoint` is probably not a great choice of key, this is a WIP to test out.

Comment: If you think a stateless approach is better, please say so. Reminds me of my Haskell days... I just find it weird _not_ to be able to see a collection of connections in one place

Comment: How about implementing a heartbeat into the clients? If the server has not received any heartbeat from a given client under a predefined period then it can consider that connection as dead and remove it from the active connections collection.

Comment: @PeterCsala you don't get to modify other people's protocols you're consuming. And even so, if your heartbeat is say 60s there's a window for the same issue - it'll be rare but it's bound to happen!